# Way of putting Semaphore obj in wait state

Tags: java, semaphore

Is there a way of putting Semaphore obj into a wait mode? For example, if I need to wait for a numbers of permits to rise to a certain number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [Semaphore.acquire(int permits)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html#acquire%28int%29). It will wait until there are `permits` permits available.

If you want to be sure that no other thread coming later can "steal" permits, so it takes the *next* available `permits` permits, create the Semaphore with `fair` set to true.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out the example at this link http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html. you can add the condition in getNextAvailableItem() method to wait for number of permits to rise to a certain number of example in the link. Share more details/description about your problem.

Comment: this doesn't show how to put semaphore into "waiting" state. As soon as one permit will be available the semaphore will let it pass, but I need something that semaphore will block until at least n number of permits are available.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I didn't understand what you were trying to do.  It sounds like [CyclicBarrier](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html) would be a better mechanism in this case.

Comment: thanks for edit, but this won't allow me to give them (threads) access to an object in pairs. Sorry I didn't specifiy that is my OP. What I need is that only two threads have access to an object and only after those two threads finish with this object another two can get access to it. Sorry once again for not specyfing this in OP.